# Is there a standard term for tests run against production?

Tags: terminology

After running our normal automated tests against a test area, we releasing the change to production then run some additional tests against production to verify the roll-out ran correctly and to test some conditions that we can reasonably duplicate in testing. This testing is intended to catch errors after they are released, but before too many users see them.

Is there a standard term for this testing? I'm tempted to call it a smoke test, but that term is already used for testing packages.

Looks like this a duplicate of:

[What would be a good term for continuous testing post-deployment?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/what-would-be-a-good-term-for-continuous-testing-post-deployment)

Comment: I've always called it "smoke testing".  In other questions I've given the same answer.  It's not so important that you use an industry standard (Because often there isn't one), but more important that you use standard terms and definitions within your project and everyone understands their meaning.

Comment: If we could agree on that within our project I wouldn't have asked it here. :)

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/what-would-be-a-good-term-for-continuous-testing-post-deployment

Comment: Can you clarify what kinds of tests you are running in production?  For example, if you are running read only test that verify correct deployment of executables, that is one thing.  If you are actually putting test data into the product database, that's entirely something else.

Comment: Just using a tool like a user would. In my case these are internal tooling to create a sandbox, build some files, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a *standard*.

We call this "Release Testing".

http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/qa-q-and-release-tests.html

Answer (score 1):

I have always called this [Acceptance Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing), it doesn't matter who the Customer is running it (at least in my world, yours will differ) so long as it has a set of Agreed upon tests to run that can be said to "Accept the release to production".

Standards in Software depends on what general set of standards you follow, but mostly it's a "depends" answer, where it depends on your corporate culture and specific industry.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [ISTQB glossary](http://istqb.org/downloads/finish/20/101.html) I would name it 'Maintenance Testing'.

Answer (score -1):

What about factory test: test to be run before going to factory, simulating the factory flow.
In my team there is a difference between factory testing and release testing. 
Not all software releases end up in factory.

Comment: it wouldn't be preproduction, since it is done in production, acting like a user

Comment: Some details in why you call them 'factory tests' would add some context to you response.